# Transposing a Range and storing in Variable. Using Variable in Index Match

Tags: excel, vba

Hi all I am working on a project and am stuck with transposing the range and storing it in a variable to be used in my index match formula.

The project consists of two worksheets: The inventory worksheet where all of the data is stored, and the ad sheet (where the data will be printed into a table). The variable d is storing the headers of the table on the ad sheet (to be used to match with names in column E of Inventory worksheet). The variable c is the active cell (where the transposed data will be printed).

Essentially I want to get the Range M2:SlastRow on the inventory worksheet, transpose it and then use that as my return range.

The Index match should match the headers from the table (one row above active cell) with the same headers in column E on the Inventory sheet. Then it should print in the active cell column the corresponding data (M:S of the Inventory sheet) and move over to the next column, repeating until the header is empty on the ad sheet.

Below is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, c As Range, d As Range, ms As Range
Dim f As String
Dim arr As Variant, arr2 As Variant

Set ws = Worksheets("Inventory")

lastRow = Application.Max(ws.Range("E100000").End(xlUp).Row, _
                       ws.Range("S100000").End(xlUp).Row)

Set c = ActiveCell
Set d = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)
Set ms = Worksheets("Inventory").Range("$M$2:$S$" & lastRow)

arr = Application.Transpose(ms)
arr2 = Application.Transpose(arr)




Do
    f = "=IFERROR(INDEX(& arr2 &, MATCH(1, INDEX((& d &=<addrE>),0,1),0)),0)"
   
    f = Replace(f, "<addrE>", "'" & ws.Name & "'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRow)
    
    c.Formula = f
    Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
    Set d = d.Offset(0.1)
Loop While Not IsEmpty(d)
```

Important to note that I am getting an "Application-defined or object-defined error" on the c.Formula = f line

Comment: You should debug and see what `f` returns - it is not a valid worksheet formula, e.g. `arr` will not be recognised. I think INDEX requires a range. If something is inside quotes it will appear on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just transpose the row that matches.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsAd As Worksheet
    Dim colE As Range, rowMS As Range, cell As Range
    Dim arr As Variant, r As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook  ' or activeworkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Inventory")
    Set wsAd = wb.Worksheets("Ad")
    lastRow = Application.Max(ws.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
                       ws.Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set colE = ws.Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
    Set rowMS = ws.Range("M1:S1")
  
    Set cell = wsAd.Range("A1")
    Do
        ' match header
        r = Application.Match(cell, colE, 0)
        If IsError(r) Then
            MsgBox "Could not match " & cell.Value, vbExclamation
        Else
            arr = Application.Transpose(rowMS.Offset(r - 1, 0))
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arr)).Value2 = arr
        End If
        Set cell = cell.Offset(0, 1)
    Loop While Not IsEmpty(cell)
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```